# Sync Active Directory Users to Outlook Contacts

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-outlook-2013, contacts

how to update and sync everyone's outlook to read the contact details from Active Directory please note that we dont have Exchange Server, just need to update the Domain User's Outlook contacts from AD

Comment: Who/what is your email host? What research have you done and what have you tried?